# bot = discord .client() TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python

I tried to deploy [this bot](https://github.com/rehmanali1337/discord-telegram-bot) on github but this error pops up

`File "/app/discord-telegram-bot/bot.py", line 35, in <module> bot = discord.Client() TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'`

I need detailed help plz !

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anywhere you defined the discord class or the Client function